# Need to display JSON with OData in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json, odata, html-table

I have some data (specifically a REST call from SharePoint) that I need to display in an HTML table. The data is formatted like a JSON object, but has various @odata entries, shown below.

```
    {  
   "@odata.context":"https://landondev-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/$metadata#files",
   "value":[  
      {  
         "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.FileServices.Folder",
         "@odata.id":"https://landondev-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/files/01PST6PHNKJZHZK2KGLFFK3YGLKDQOGQP6",
         "@odata.etag":"\"{954F4EAA-4669-4A59-ADE0-CB50E0E341FE},2\"",
         "@odata.editLink":"me/files/01PST6PHNKJZHZK2KGLFFK3YGLKDQOGQP6",
         "createdBy":{  
            "application":null,
            "user":{  
               "id":"7a55eb6c-869a-49c9-b434-f9fabbdc11ea",
               "displayName":"Landon James"
            }
         },
         "eTag":"\"{954F4EAA-4669-4A59-ADE0-CB50E0E341FE},2\"",
         "id":"01PST6PHNKJZHZK2KGLFFK3YGLKDQOGQP6",
         "lastModifiedBy":{  
            "application":null,
            "user":{  
               "id":"7a55eb6c-869a-49c9-b434-f9fabbdc11ea",
               "displayName":"Landon James"
            }
         },
         "name":"Shared with Everyone",
         "parentReference":{  
            "driveId":"01VHTMAA4U4KFOAOD2BBEKDTQSP7KTSSSS",
            "id":"01PST6PHN6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
            "path":"/"
         },
         "size":0,
         "dateTimeCreated":"2015-07-31T14:52:53Z",
         "dateTimeLastModified":"2015-07-31T16:24:24Z",
         "type":"Folder",
         "webUrl":"https://landondev-my.sharepoint.com/personal/landon_landondev_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Shared%20with%20Everyone",
         "childCount":2
      }]}
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to cleanly pull the data I need (specifically the name and dateTimeCreated properties) out of this file. After a lot of looking around I've only gotten more confused about the OData format. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and JSON so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! To get good answers, I think you might need to be a bit more precise about what you want to do. What have you tried so far? What result have that produced? How would the result you want to have look? Perhaps read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You mean parse the json payload?

```
var data = '{"@odata.context":"context","value":[{"Id":1,"Name":"test","dateTimeCreated":"2015-07-31T14:52:53Z"}]}';
response = JSON.parse(data);
alert(response['value'][0]['Name']);
alert(response['value'][0]['dateTimeCreated']);
```